Mock unit tests
For a "professional" project that's created to look for funding, are mocks from unit tests recommended to be the old fashion way by creating each mock from scratch or is it ok with just using foundry's mockCall()?
I mean, after using mockCall I can see how details can slip by with a call that wasn't mocked correctly, while by just creating the mock from scratch, the call would just revert (this is one example ofc).
What do you guys think would be the correct approach to having a well tested system?
